# Repeating a pytorch tensor without copying memory

Tags: memory, pytorch, tensor

Does `pytorch` support repeating a tensor **without allocating significantly more memory**?

Assume we have a tensor

```
t = torch.ones((1,1000,1000))
t10 = t.repeat(10,1,1)
```

Repeating `t` 10 times will require take 10x the memory. Is there a way how I can create a tensor `t10` without allocating significantly more memory?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153237/pytorch-embedding-tensor-in-another-without-copying) is a related question, but without answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`torch.expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand)

```
t = torch.ones((1, 1000, 1000))
t10 = t.expand(10, 1000, 1000)
```

Keep in mind that the `t10` is just a reference to `t`. So for example, a change to `t10[0,0,0]` will result in the same change in `t[0,0,0]` and every member of `t10[:,0,0]`.

Other than direct access, most operations performed on `t10` will cause memory to be copied which will break the reference and cause more memory to be used. For example: changing the device (`.cpu()`, `.to(device=...)`, `.cuda()`), changing the datatype (`.float()`, `.long()`, `.to(dtype=...)`), or using `.contiguous()`.