torch.cat on torch.expand tensors
Consider the code below. I am creating two tensors using torch.expand, and they are using little memory 0.67GB. But when I use torch.cat to concatenate them, a whole lot more memory is used 7.3GB. Is there a way around this to still cat tensors while keeping memory usage low?
import torch

device    = torch.device('cuda')

def print_cuda_mem(device=device, location=''):
    total_mem = torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).total_memory / 1e9
    reser_mem = torch.cuda.memory_reserved(0) /1e9
    alloc_mem = torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0) /1e9
    print(f'{location}, memory allocation on GPU {total_mem=:0.6g}GB, {reser_mem=:0.6g}GB, {alloc_mem=:0.6g}GB')
    return reser_mem,alloc_mem

dtype = torch.float32
dsize = 4  # in bytes, size of one float32 (4) or float64 (8)


#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59757933/repeating-a-pytorch-tensor-without-copying-memory

arr_1 = torch.arange(1024*20*64*64*1,dtype=dtype,device=device).reshape(1024,20,64,64,1).expand([-1,-1,-1,-1,10])
arr_2 = torch.arange(1024*20*64*64*1,dtype=dtype,device=device).reshape(1024,20,64,64,1).expand([-1,-1,-1,-1,10])

_  , alloc_repeat = print_cuda_mem(device=device,location='after creation')

arr_cat = torch.cat((arr_1,arr_2),axis=1)

_ , alloc_cat = print_cuda_mem(device=device,location='after cat')


